# Trigger some action on Ctrl-Right Click on Desktop ( using JAVA )

Tags: java, windows

I need to write one JAVA application.
The requirement is ,

> when the user clicked anywhere in the
>   screen ( It may be upon an icon in
>   Desktop or upon one word in Microft
>   word ) , my java program should be
>   notified to do some action.

How can I write such an application.

Comment: No, that would require JNI. I'm not going to post this as an answer, though, because I don't know enough about the Windows APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about creating a system wide hook (windows API call [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) with WM_MOUSE or WM_MOUSELL).  This is not for the faint of heart.  Doing this for a single process that you own is a bit tricky.  Doing it system-wide (for processes that you don't own) is really, really tricky - lot's of pitfalls (I'm pretty sure I've hit every single one), and this is one severely under-documented area of the Win32 API.

This will absolutely require using the Windows API, as well as DLLs, an understanding of injection of DLLs into different processes and a host of other things.  Java isn't going to get this particular job done (in fact, based on your specification, I can't imagine why Java would be the language of choice here).

Time to break out the C.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have any standard functionality allowing this. You must talk directmy to Windows using JNI or JNA, or use a third party library doing that.

For this particular purpose a Microsoft language would probably be best, but it is still a very tricky thing to have to dó.